# OneDrive and DropBox on iPhone will not sync if they are closed

Tags: iphone, icloud, dropbox, onedrive

My OneDrive and DropBox will not sync photos on my iPhone unless they are opened. I have checked both apps settings and they are allowed to run in the background. Also, both are allowed to use cellular data. So, basically, I followed all the recommendations however it seems they only sync when they are opened. iCloud syncs fine and I can see all my photos in the cloud.

Any idea or tips on how to make OneDrive and DropBox work in the background?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Check if you have Low power mode enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked now, Low Power Mode is disabled already. Anything else I should check?

Comment: When you say "opened", do you mean "focused", as in they're the active application?  You're not closing them from the task lister, are you?

Comment: I mean "Active" because I always close the apps when I don't need them. However, they should be still able to run in the background, right?

Comment: If you are killing them, no, they will not be running any longer.  Stop doing that, there is no reason for it.  "Run in background" gives timeslices to a running application, it does not launch an application that is not already running.